# Not able to use Custom XIB outlets with UICollectionViewCell

Tags: xamarin.ios, custom-controls, xib, uicollectionviewcell

When accessing to outlets from my CustomClass : UICollectionViewCell, they are appearing as not initialized and can not set a proper value.

Every example I've seen it uses a plain Class (no XIB) to set the UI.

```
[Register("CustomCommentCell")]
public partial class CustomCommentCell : UICollectionViewCell
{
    public static readonly NSString Identifier = new NSString("CustomCommentCell");

    public CustomCommentCell () : base()
    {
    }

    public CustomCommentCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public void updateData()
    {
        this.lblComment.Text = "Test";
    }
}
```

On the other hand, I have registered the Class:
this.tableComments.RegisterClassForCell (typeof(CustomCommentCell),commentCellId);

and have the GetCell properly set.
However, when trying to set the outlets to a specific value, it indicates it is null. (this.lblcomment = null) while it should have been a UILabel initialized.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

to create the Custom CollectionViewCell using XIB. do the following

1) create C# class which inherits from UIcollectionViewCell

```
[Register("MyCustomCell")]
public class MyCustomCell : UICollectionViewCell
{

    public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString ("MyCustomCell");

    [Export ("initWithFrame:")]
    public MyCustomCell(CoreGraphics.CGRect frame) : base (frame)
    {



    }

    public override UIView ContentView {
        get {
            var arr=    NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib ("MyCustomCell", this, null);
            UIView view =arr.GetItem<UIView> (0);
            view.Frame = base.ContentView.Frame;
            base.ContentView.AddSubview (view);
            return base.ContentView;
        }
    }

}
```

2) Add a IphoneView XIB file has the Same Name as that of Class created in step 1

3) Open XIB in XCODE and do the Following Changes

[image]

3.1)Select the FileOwner set the Class same name as Step 1
[image]
   3.2)Select The View Set the Class name UIView

4) Design Your XIB Accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I can't follow quite the problem you are seeing. What is a "Custom XIB outlet"? Why is this question tagged "custom-controls"? Is there some example code or pictures you can show to help explain the problem?

---

The approach I use for UICollectionViewCell's is the same as I use for UITableViewCell - see the tutorial - http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/uitableviewcell-using-xib-editor.html

---

**Update:** From the code you've posted as a comment (not sure if it's complete or not), I think it would be useful for you to follow through that tutorial. There are a few steps to complete including registering the custom class name and including using `RegisterNibForCellReuse` - one of those will probably fix this for you.

Comment: Edit your question and paste full code in there - I can't read that in the comment.

Comment: I have added  this.tableComments.RegisterClassForCell instead.    this.tableComments.RegisterClassForCell (typeof(CustomCommentCell),commentCellId);

Comment: If i remove that, i get an error within the GetCell method. Everything seems to work, and outlets are appearing within intellisense, but just not initialized.

Comment: Try the sample tutorial or post more code. I can't debug your problems in comments like this. I can tell you that the flow in http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/uitableviewcell-using-xib-editor.html works and that I use that same flow for collection cells as well as table ones.

Comment: To better description, i'm having the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750402/ios-uicollectionviewcontroller-not-showing-center-cells-but-can-click-on-them/15209293#15209293